# Callback on ascx files

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, devexpress

When I try to run `.PerformCallback` command on `.ascx` file I got an error. Here is the error alert..

[image: Callback Error]

How can i resolve it?

Comment: can you show your ascx markup and ascx.cs code?

Comment: here is my example project..
http://www.2shared.com/file/sl-SnXet/WebApplication6.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you do not restore page’s controls hierarchy after it has been changed once.

Use recommendations from the http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/K18291.aspx KB Article to resolve this issue.